# Digest::CRC32 with Zlib

Tags: ruby, digest

In my code, I need to hash files using a variety of algorithms, including CRC32. Since I'm also using other cryptographic hash functions in the `Digest` family, I thought it would be nice to maintain a consistent interface for them all.

For the record, I did find [`digest-crc`](https://github.com/postmodern/digest-crc), a gem which does exactly what I want. The thing is, `Zlib` is part of the standard library and has a working implementation of CRC32 that I'd like to reuse. Also, it is written in C so it should offer superior performance in relation to `digest-crc`, which is a pure-ruby implementation.

Implementing `Digest::CRC32` actually looked pretty straightforward at first:

```
%w(digest zlib).each { |f| require f }

class Digest::CRC32 < Digest::Class
  include Digest::Instance

  def update(str)
    @crc32 = Zlib.crc32(str, @crc32)
  end

  def initialize; reset; end
  def reset; @crc32 = 0; end
  def finish; @crc32.to_s; end
end
```

Everything looks right:

```
crc32 = File.open('Rakefile') { |f| Zlib.crc32 f.read }
digest = Digest::CRC32.file('Rakefile').digest!.to_i
crc32 == digest
=> true
```

Unfortunately, not everything works:

```
Digest::CRC32.file('Rakefile').hexdigest!
=> "313635393830353832"

# What I actually expected was:
Digest::CRC32.file('Rakefile').digest!.to_i.to_s(16)
=> "9e4a9a6"
```

`hexdigest` basically returns `Digest.hexencode(digest)`, [which works with the value of the digest at the byte level](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/ext/digest/digest.c#L81). I'm not sure how that function works, so I was wondering if it is possible to achieve this with just the integer returned from `Zlib.crc32`.

Comment: What ruby platform are you working on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Digest is expecting digest to return the raw bytes that make up the checksum, i.e. in the case of a crc32 the 4 bytes that makeup that 32bit integer. However you are instead returning a string that contains the base 10 representation of that integer.

You want something like

```
[@crc32].pack('V')
```

to turn that integer into the bytes that represent that. Do go and read up on pack and its various format specifiers - there are lots of ways of packing an integer depending on whether the bytes should be presented in native endian-ness, big-endian, little-endian etc so you should figure out which one matches your needs

Comment: I used [@crc32].pack('N') to get my version of Digest::CRC32.file(filename) to work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry this doesn't really answer your question but it might help..

Firstly, when reading in a file, make sure you pass the "rb" parameter. I can see you're not on windows but if by chance your code does end up getting ran on a windows machine your code won't work the same, especially when reading ruby files in. Example:

```
crc32 = File.open('test.rb') { |f| Zlib.crc32 f.read }
#=> 189072290
digest = Digest::CRC32.file('test.rb').digest!.to_i
#=> 314435800
crc32 == digest
#=> false

crc32 = File.open('test.rb', "rb") { |f| Zlib.crc32 f.read }
#=> 314435800
digest = Digest::CRC32.file('test.rb').digest!.to_i
#=> 314435800
crc32 == digest
#=> true
```

The above will work across all platforms and all rubies.. that I know of..
But that's not what you asked..

I'm pretty sure the hexdigest and digest methods in your above example are working as they should though..

```
dig_file = Digest::CRC32.file('test.rb')

test1 = dig_file.hexdigest
#=> "333134343335383030"

test2 = dig_file.digest
#=> "314435800"

def hexdigest_to_digest(h)
  h.unpack('a2'*(h.size/2)).collect {|i| i.hex.chr }.join
end

test3 = hexdigest_to_digest(test1)
#=> "314435800"
```

So I'm guessing either the .to_i.to_s(16) is throwing off your expected result or your expected result may possibly be wrong? Not sure, but all the best

Comment: You're onto something there; I think the answer is the opposite of that: digest to hexdigest. I tried something with `unpack` before to try to force base 16 but really I had no idea what I was doing. I still don't understand it.

Comment: `digest` outputs the "correct" checksum because it just returns what the `finish` method returns. In reality, it should return a binary string suitable for `Digest.hexencode`, which should encode the bytes in hexadecimal. So yeah, it seems both my methods are broken. :)

Answer (score 3):

It works just fine, make sure to always use the network byte order, like this:

```
def finish; [@crc32].pack('N'); end
```